# os.rmtree really remove something in the present of error?

Tags: python, shutil

with this Error, was some files or directories removed from /shared/doc?
is the damage done?

What I am hoping for is nothing get removed.

thanks

```
    shutil.rmtree('/shared/doc')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/shared/doc/past/v01/5.pdf'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutil.rmtree()` is *not* an atomic transaction:

if something fails the command will stop, but it will not be able to undo any harm that has already been done, so you might end up with a half-deleted directory.

Comment: thanks, as you mentioned, a few not all directories removed before error happened, files are restored, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to predict what got deleted already without looking at the directory itself.

`shutil.rmtree()` would've stopped once it got into the `Permission denied` error, but it would've deleted files till it get into this error.

Comment: You are right, it is exactly as what you said, it did remove a few directories and stopped when error happened. thanks